# Exception: Document [spreadsheet id] is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Recently more and more often my script runs into this error, which didn't happen before and the script was not changed in between.

[image]

1. the file id refers to the script container, and my has the edit right to the file
2. it is run upon time trigger

These really causes big trouble to the daily operation - does anyone also encounter such errors and have any idea of how to solve it?